# Windows Form Progress Bar slows code run time

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, progress-bar

I have tried many different options with running a progress bar with a cancellation option during runtime and they all dramatically slow my code. Is there a best way to accomplish this?
I have tried Background worker, Async/Await, Task Queues and just simple multithreading. All to keep UI accessible to users when the longer process run. Is the best option to avoid the Progress bar control and go custom?

Comment: Personally, I've never noticed an issue with the `ProgressBar` control. Maybe you could do what you should have done in the first place and [provide code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your issue. It's quite possibly something that you're doing wrong.

Comment: Please show us all four of the attempts you've tried. We can help you fix them all. What we're not going to do is code up a complete solution from scratch. Give us your attempts please.

Comment: So your code runs fast without a `ProgressBar`, and becomes slow when you add a `ProgressBar` in the mix? How often is your code updating the `ProgressBar`?